# AMP Form always showing submit-error, even on response code 200

Tags: go, amp-html

I am using AMP form to send data to my Golang server. Even if I skip all handling of data sent and just write response with the code 200 as is said in AMP form reference, I still get shown the submit-error template.

This is my form (I skipped the fields because it would be too long)

```
<form action-xhr="/contactus" method="POST" class="contactForm" target="_top" custom-validation-reporting="show-all-on-submit" id="contactForm">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- divs with input and submit button -->
    </fieldset>
    <div submit-success>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            Success! 
        </template>
    </div>
    <div submit-error>
        <template type="amp-mustache">
            Error! 
        </template>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is an example of server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 23 Sep 2018 21:48:15 GMT
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/x-gzip
```

Could the problem be on server side? 
I can't figure it out... Any idea is much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46480932/5635098 hope this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel embarrassed.
After a couple of days wondering and getting back to this issue, when I finally decide to post a question, an idea struck me right after I do it...

The problem is with header `Content-type`. It must be set to JSON:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you implement AMP CORS headers.

Refer: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-caches-and-cors/amp-cors-requests?referrer=ampproject.org

If requests are for your own origin (your domain and not amp cached servers) then you can set following headers-

```
if (req.headers['amp-same-origin'] === 'true') {
    origin = req.query.__amp_source_origin;
    sourceOrigin = origin;
}

res.set({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin,
    'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin': sourceOrigin,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin': 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin',
    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' + ', AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin' + ', Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'
});
```